# IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tentei resolver o exercício https://python.nilo.pro.br/exercicios/capitulo%2007/exercicio-07-09.html
e mesmo o gabarito apresenta um erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):  File "teste.py", line 59, in <module>
>     linhas[3][3] = "O"
> IndexError: list assignment index out of range
> ```

O código completo é esse:

```
palavras = [
          "casa",
          "bola",
          "mangueira",
          "uva",
          "quiabo",
          "computador",
          "cobra",
          "lentilha",
          "arroz"
     ]

índice = int(input("Digite um numero:"))
palavra = palavras[ (índice * 776) % len(palavras)]
for x in range(100):
     print()
digitadas = []
acertos = []
erros = 0

linhas_txt = """
X==:==
X  :
X
X
X
X
=======

"""

linhas = []

for linha in linhas_txt.splitlines():
     linhas.append(list(linha))

while True:
     senha = ""
     for letra in palavra:
         senha += letra if letra in acertos else "."
     print(senha)
     if senha == palavra:
         print("Você acertou!")
         break
     tentativa = input("\nDigite uma letra:").lower().strip()
     if tentativa in digitadas:
         print("Você já tentou esta letra!")
         continue
     else:
         digitadas += tentativa
         if tentativa in palavra:
               acertos += tentativa
         else:
               erros += 1
               print("Você errou!")
               if erros == 1:
                    linhas[3][3] = "O"
               elif erros == 2:
                    linhas[4][3] = "|"
               elif erros == 3:
                    linhas[4][2] = "\\"
               elif erros == 4:
                    linhas[4][4] = "/"
               elif erros == 5:
                    linhas[5][2] = "/"
               elif erros == 6:
                    linhas[5][4] = "\\"

     for l in linhas:
          print("".join(l))
     if erros == 6:
         print("Enforcado!")
         print("A palavra secreta era: %s" % palavra)
         break
```

Alguém tem ideia de onde esta o problema?

Comment: Coloquei pra rodar aqui e deu o mesmo erro, tentando descobrir o que está errado.

Comment: Se a resposta atendeu os seus objetivos, não esqueça de aceitá-la.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string que representa a forca precisa ter espaços vazios para que possam ser substituídos pelas partes do enforcado conforme os erros forem acontecendo. No fragmento de código abaixo acrescente 6 espaços em cada linha ao lado de cada X a partir da terceira linha.

```
linhas_txt = """
X==:==
X  :
X      
X      
X      
X      
=======

"""
```

Assim a cada letra que você errar, o espaço vazio será substituído pela parte do corpo do enforcado, de acordo com o que diz o fragmento abaixo:

```
if erros == 1:
    linhas[3][3] = "O"
elif erros == 2:
    linhas[4][3] = "|"
elif erros == 3:
    linhas[4][2] = "\\"
elif erros == 4:
    linhas[4][4] = "/"
elif erros == 5:
    linhas[5][2] = "/"
elif erros == 6:
    linhas[5][4] = "\\"
```

Comment: Realmente não tinha me dado conta que eu precisava criar um espaço para inserir o str. Muito obrigado pela atenção.